# Unrecognized selector when calling delegate Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, splitview

I'm trying to implement a SplitViewController with a NavigationController in both master and detail. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial), however I'm still running into a rather strange problem.
When I try to call the delegate method I get `-[UINavigationController selectedStudent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...`

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Here's the code:

StudentSelectionDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Student;
@protocol StudentSelectionDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)selectedStudent:(Student *)newStudent;
@end
```

StudentDetail represents detail in the split view. 
In StudentDetail.h I`ve got

```
#import "StudentSelectionDelegate.h"
@interface StudentDetail : UITableViewController <StudentSelectionDelegate>
...
```

StudentDetail.m

```
@synthesize SentStudent;
...
-(void)selectedStudent:(Student *)newStudent
{
    [self setStudent:newStudent];
}
```

StudentList represents master of the splitview. In StudentList.h I`ve got :

```
#import "StudentSelectionDelegate.h"
...
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<StudentSelectionDelegate> delegate;
```

In StudentList.m in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
[self.delegate selectedStudent:SelectedStudent];
```

And no "SelectedStudent" is not null

And finally AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "StudentDetail.h"
#import "StudentListNew.h"
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *leftNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    StudentListNew  *leftViewController = (StudentListNew *)[leftNavController topViewController];
    StudentDetail  *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    leftViewController.delegate = rightViewController;

    return YES;
}
```

P.S. I have been searching for a solution for hours.

Comment: Is `rightViewController` really a `StudentDetail` instance?  When you call `selectedStudent:` log the delegate's class to see if you have the right object type there.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're reinventing the wheel?  The Xcode Master-Detail Application template already does this correctly.

Comment: @PetahChristian He's learning. Reinventing wheels is what students do.

Comment: @Petha Christian I have already write a lot of code and don`t want to rewrite it.

Comment: @PhillipMills I think that's it i tried it with  `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedStudent:)]) {
            [self.delegate selectedStudent:SelectedStudent];
        }`
and it does not seem to respond to said selector.
What do I do now ?

Comment: Given the `UINavigationController` in the exception message, it's clear the delegate is not a `StudentDetail` object...

Comment: What you do now is find the **real** `StudentDetail` and make **it** the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]` is a `UINavigationController`, not a `StudentDetail`.

The error message is telling you that `UINavigationController` does not have a `selectedStudent` property.

Your delegate is not pointing to a `StudentDetail` but a navigation controller, which doesn't even implement `< StudentSelectionDelegate>`.  However, since you specified the cast, Objective C can't warn you that the object you cast isn't actually the kind of class that you cast it to be.

You should consider type checking the objects, as Apple's code does, to make sure that objects are the class you expect them to be.

Here's the corrected code:

```
UINavigationController *rightNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
StudentDetail  *rightViewController = (StudentDetail *)[rightNavController topViewController];
leftViewController.delegate = rightViewController;
```

As for making sure that your delegate implements the method,

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedStudent:)]) {
    [self.delegate selectedStudent:SelectedStudent];
}
```

would have spared you from the exception, although you'd have to have used the debugger to realize that self.delegate wasn't a `StudentDetail`.

Comment: You sir are my hero !

Comment: @Hadjimina If you're interested in learning about other approaches to pass information to a view controller, check out `prepareForSegue`.  It can be used in place of the delegate and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: That's what i did in the beginning. However I didn`t get that to work and thought that the delegate thing was more proffessionell